# Why do notebooks created from terminal break on opening next time?

Tags: notebooks

**Background:**: I am running Mathematica on macOS Catalina. I have a workflow where I heavily depend on the terminal to create directories, sub-directories and navigate through them. In each of these directories, I often have to put some Mathematica notebooks relevant to the topic of the directory. What I do at the moment is that I keep an instance of Mathematica open and whenever I have to create a new notebook, I create it, enter the contents in the notebook Finally, to save it at the specified location, I would have to open the save dialog box and then navigate to the directory I created and then save it there. This becomes inconvenient as I have a lot of directories, each named by a specific sequence of characters and numbers, and locating the target directory takes up a minute or two. Also, I find it redundant to do this long process every time.

**What I tried:** When I create the directory and navigate into it, I immediately create the notebook file uisng the touch command, something like this:

```
$ mkdir 20211126-test-dir
$ cd 20211126-test-dir
$ touch sample.nb
$ open sample.nb
```

The notebook file gets created. When I open it with Mathematica it works fine and I start writing my code. Here is a sample code to test out:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -6, 6}]
```

I evaluate the code and get the expected plot. After that, I just save the notebook with `Ctrl + s`, and then I close the notebook.

When I open the notebook next time, everything is broken. The output graphics is missing but the code that I had entered is still present. The content of the file simply appears like it is a plain text. Everything appears in a single cell:

```
In[2]:= Plot[Sin[x],{x,-6,6}]
Out[2]=
```

What is causing this problem? Is there a way to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem on Linux.  After you open and evaluate sample.nb, try the File->SaveAs menu item (shft-ctl-s).  Notice the default file type is plain text.  The file extension is ".nb", but the file is *not*  a notebook file.  That explains why File->Save does not save in the notebook format.  A solution could be to use File->SaveAs and change the file type to notebook.

Comment: I think just creating an empty file with `touch` is not enough to make this work. I would think doing something like `echo "Notebook[{}]" > sample.nb` instead might be enough to make your workflow work, but it might well be that a bit more content than that needs to be added, for that I would suggest to experiment yourself...

Comment: @AlbertRetey Thank you for the idea. I guess I will use this for now. I hope this is fixed in the future though.